# website is not accessing database after updating dll file from bin folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I am new in asp.net website development...I have created my asp.net C# with sql server database and hosted it on server and it is running fine...now my problem is that when i update my website only .aspx files are updated and aspx.cs files are not updated...someone gave me suggestion that if I update my dll file after built website on visual studio than it will work fine and i did it but now the problem is that it is not accessing previous data which was stored before this updation...kindly help me

Comment: did you store your data in SQL server? Did you check the server if the data is there?

Comment: Make sure it works on your local machine and the bin contains the correct dll files then upload it again. Often on the local machine it works because the DLL are in the GAC so even if you do not have the correct once in the bin it works.